# Need an If Statement syntax explanation

Tags: java

Forgive my foolishness, but I want to know in the part of code below:

```
String titleTag = "<title>";
String endTitleTag = "</title>";
int titleStart = line.indexOf(titleTag);
int titleEnd = line.indexOf(endTitleTag);

if (titleStart != -1 && titleEnd != -1) 
{
String title = line.substring(titleStart + titleTag.length(),titleEnd);

if (checkTitleIfMatched(title)) {
System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s", title, location));

word.set(title);
context.write(word, location);
  }
}
```

What is the role of the **-1**, why we make this ,let's say,  comparison?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should read the documentation of indexOf API

Comment: `line.indexOf(titleTag)` returns -1 if `titleTag` does not occur in the string or 0 and above if the string is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `indexOf` method returns the index of the searched string. If the string is not found, it returns `-1`. That's why you have that comparison, it's to make sure that the searched string is found.

Comment: thanks man. still learning java you know...

Answer (score 0):

Considering `indexOf` is the method of `String` API then it will return -1 when no matching input string is found.

Answer (score 0):

indexOf returns -1 on no match.  See javadocs here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)